# How to optimize an algorithm for sorting OCR detected text chunks in the right order?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-vision

Consider the following paragraph along with detected word and equation chunks:

[image: example ocr result]

While the **green** rectangles highlight a text section, the **blue** rectangles highlight individual words and equations. The selections were retrieved from using both the google vision api as well as the mathpix ocr api.

All of the rectangles have been extracted and labeled as either "block", "word" or "math" along with its **coordinates on the image** ([*top-left*, *top-right*, *bottom-right*, *bottom-left*] - (X, Y) for each) and its **text value** (e.g. "Der").

Each rectangle inside a block is saved as a child of said block so one can easily iterate through all the children of a block.

The task now becomes to extract the words inside a block based on their order and line breaks. This example contains printed text, however the OCR algorithm can also detect handwritten text and math - which may lead to more volatility in the top coordinates of words on the same line of text.

The question now becomes what the fastest way to sort these results would be.

**First approach**

The first approach I've tried is to iterate through the words in a block and keep track of them in a map of **y ranges**, so that each entry in the map would represent a line.

```py
lines = {
  [10, 20]: ["Der", "entsprechende", "Kapitalwert", "der", "Zahlungsreihe", "beträgt" ...],
  [25, 35]: ["next", "line"]
}
```

One would then iterate through each line and sort the words by their x coordinate in ascending order.

This comes with the drawback of having to iterate through all the entries of the map for every single word in order to check that the y value is within the range of the two values.

Is there perhaps a way to represent the individual ranges as a unique value (perhaps using hashes?) and saving each line to the corresponding hash?

Order-preserving hash functions could be the way to go for ordered values, but it's unclear how those could be applied to ranges with a threshold.

**What Google gives you**

As mentioned the results have been obtained by using the google vision api for document text detection among other things. Google already provides you with a "full annotation" of the scanned document but the results of individual paragraphs do not appear to be ordered. Perhaps there is a way to leverage the results provided by the vision api.

Comment: i'm not sure I understand the problem ... what about using the centerpoint to sort after?

Comment: It is not clear how your tests work. However, for what I understand you are only trying to order correctly text in an image. The problem here is that if the text correspond to an image that does not contain ordered text, let's say a "traffic sign" or a tax document it will be difficult for the API to order, it will be expected.
Could you please share an API response where no order is presented vs what is expected? Your example image should be ordered if sent to the API, it will be helpful to see the full picture